# Remove &#13; from python string

Tags: python, popen, newline

When you run something through `popen` in Python, the results come in from the buffer with the CR-LF decimal value of a carriage return (13) at the end of each line. How do you remove this from a Python string?

Comment: Doesn't popen support the 'b' mode flag to turn on binary mode which might get rid of the \r to begin with.

Comment: binary mode would be the one that *keeps* the \r.  Text mode might get rid of it.

Comment: Actually, `'b'` would force `'\r'` to be preserved (if it's supported -- didn't check).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply do

```
s = s.replace('\r\n', '\n')
```

to replace all occurrences of CRNL with just NL, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Also need to add .rstrip("\r\n") for trailing CRLF

Answer (score 2):

```
buffer = "<text from your subprocess here>\r\n"
no_cr = buffer.replace("\r\n", "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

If they are at the end of the string(s), I would suggest to use:

```
buffer = "<text from your subprocess here>\r\n"
no_cr = buffer.rstrip("\r\n")
```

You can also use rstrip() without parameters which will remove whitespace as well.

Answer (score 1):

replace('\r\n','\n') should work, but sometimes it just does not. How strange. Instead you can use this:

```
lines = buffer.split('\r')
cleanbuffer = ''
for line in lines: cleanbuffer = cleanbuffer + line
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can simply do the following:

```
s = s.strip()
```

This will remove any extraneous whitespace, including CR and LFs, leading or trailing the string.

```
s = s.rstrip()
```

Does the same, but only trailing the string.

That is:

```
s = '  Now is the time for all good...  \t\n\r   "
s = s.strip()
```

s now contains 'Now is the time for all good...'

```
s = s.rstrip()
```

s now contains '  Now is the time for all good...'

See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html for more.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `s = s.replace('\r', '')` too.