# How can I get rid of the '/n' character in front of every line in a text file?

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract some data from a text file, and my resulting text file has '/n' at the beginning of every new line.

I have tried using

```
line = line.strip()
```

and

```
line = line.remove('/n','')
```

but the problem remains.

I expected:

```
Name: A
Age: 20
```

but this appears

```
Name: A
/nAge: 20
Name: B
/nAge: 25
```

Comment: Please post some source code

Comment: It is obviously the case that your resulting string that you write to file simply contains `'/n'`. Just look through your code and correct it.

Comment: Please post your source code.

Comment: `s.lstrip("/n")`...

Comment: This method should also work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759619/remove-13-from-python-string

Comment: `/n` or `\n`? And how is `line` getting set in the first place?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  What is this `remove` function you're calling?

Answer (score 1):

notice that `/n` (what you have) is not `\n`(which is new line) and is why line.strip() don't work. you can do

```
line = line.replace("/n","")
```

which should sort it

Comment: `strip` also takes arguments so could simply be `strip("/n")`